# Undefined offset on multiple lines

Tags: php

I have written a small program to solve a mathematical problem. But when I run, it gives an undefined offset error on line number 9,11,13,15.
I have searched various questions, but didn't find anything useful.
What might be causing this.   ?

```
<?php
$arr = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15];
$tries=0;
$answer=0;
while(($answer!=30) && ($tries!=1000))
{
    $tries = $tries+1;
    $num1=getRandomNumber();
    $num2=getRandomNumber();
    $num3=getRandomNumber();
    $num4=getRandomNumber();
    $num5=getRandomNumber();
    if($num5 + $num4 + $num3 + $num2 + $num1 == 30)
    {
        $answer = 30;
        echo $num1 + "+"  + $num2 + "+" + $num3 + "+" + $num4 + "+" + $num5 + " = 30";
        break;
    }
}
if($tries==1000)
{
    echo "1000 tries completed";
}


function getRandomNumber()
{
    $arr = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15];
    $r = mt_rand(1,15);
    if(($r%2)!=0)
    {
        return $arr[$r];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your array has 8 numbers in it, so indexes 0->7, but you're generating random indexes 1->15.

Comment: Ah! that's a stupid mistake from my side. I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `getRandomNumber()` function, you're generating an array index between `1` and `15`, but your array is only `8` elements long.

To fix this, update the call to `mt_rand()` to support your actual array size:

```
$r = mt_rand(0, count($arr) - 1);
```

*Side-note* (not answer specific), string concatenation in PHP is done with the period, `.` and not the `+`:

```
echo $num1 + "+"  + $num2 + "+" + $num3 + "+" + $num4 + "+" + $num5 + " = 30";
// should be:
echo $num1 . "+"  . $num2 . "+" . $num3 . "+" . $num4 . "+" . $num5 . " = 30";
```

Comment: Ah! I got confused between java and php for the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

You should change line:

```
$r = mt_rand(1,15);
```

into

```
$r = mt_rand(0,count($arr)-1);
```

because your `$arr` in your `getRandomNumber` function has only 8 elements (not 16)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRandomNumber()
{
    $arr = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15];
    $r = mt_rand(1,15);
    if(($r%2)!=0)
    {
        return $arr[$r];
    }
}
```

The `mt_rand` function returns a number higher then the array index witch is 7. You can either extend the array and make it have 16 index or reduce the range in `mt_rand` function to 0-7.